# The ability to have pretty formatted HTML with Next Js

Tags: reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering

I am using the Nextjs framework and my pages are dynamically generated.

When I view the page source code - it is displayed in an unreadable format.

Is it possible to create a 'pretty' formatted HTML for the application created with NextJs?

I have such request from an SEO optimization manager.

[image: View page source modal]

[image: Page source]

Comment: Does using the inspector achieve your goal? The inspector is the next option down in the menu photo.

Comment: The main goal is to have a pretty formatted output HTML. It is a request of the SEO optimization manager.

Comment: https://swc.rs/docs/configuration/minification

Comment: I actually get why this was asked. When you use inspector, you get formatted HTML whether you are using Next or CRA - there is something about viewing source (and it being formatted) that strangely assures one that their content is truly server side rendered. Call it OCD or whatever but I get why the question was asked....even though as rightfully answered, its not necessary.

Comment: The inspector does not show you what HTML was delivered from the server; it shows you what the HTML DOM tree current is. These are very, very different things.

In production, having the server return minified/compressed HTML is great for the end user. In development, it's sometimes a chore to wade through compressed HTML to find what you're looking for. Debugging an SSR bug in a large site can be quite painful, and the burden would be less if the HTML could be pretty-printed natively out of Next.js.

Answer (score 3):

Received this answer from NextJs team

> There is no "options" within Next.js to achieve this.
>
> One way to do it would be to create a custom server and prettify the
> response yourself. While I don't advocate to make a custom server just
> for this, some might have found success in doing so.
>
> I find it "weird" to prettify HTML for SEO reason though. Search
> engines are well capable of parsing minified HTML and "prettifying"
> the output will add weight to the page.
>
> More height means less performance and that could impact SEO in a
> negative way.

Comment: They may find it "weird" but until we live in a world where we can rely on all tools to reliably and properly pretty print the output when inspecting a response it's still a nice quality of life feature. Alas, we don't live in such a world.